# Oracle Bulk Collect - Limit number

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-collect

I read about `Bulk Collect` and wrote some code using it (not deployed yet). The total amount of rows returned is in the vicinity of 80.000. I limited the amount of rows returned in one batch to 10.000, but there is no basis for using this number, I simply improvised.

What would be a good method for determining how to limit the `Bulk Collect`?

Comment: Here's an article by Steven Feuerstein in Oracle Magazine which looks at [BULK COLLECT and LIMIT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html). Oracle internally does convert Cursor FOR loops to BULK COLLECTS using a limit of 100.

Answer (score 2):

As with anything, the best approach would be to benchmark the different options.

Realistically, though, in the vast majority of cases, there isn't any appreciable benefit to a limit much higher than 100.  With a limit of 100, you're eliminating 99% of the context shifts.  It's relatively unlikely that the remaining 1% of the context shifts account for a meaningful fraction of the execution time of your code.  Reducing the context shifts further probably does nothing for performance and just causes you to use more valuable PGA memory.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I had no idea about the magnitude of LIMIT. 10, 100, 1000, 10000? I have some perspective now. Would you be so kind to point me in the right direction regarding benchmarking this thing?

Comment: @Robotron - The same way you'd benchmark anything.  Depending on how sophisticated you want to get, it could be anywhere between doing a full blown load test with a bunch of threads to a simple single-user SQL*Plus session where you measure the elapsed time of the two calls.